# Is there a way to get Ethereum price data using the Coinbase API?

Tags: ethereum, coinbase-api, cryptocurrency

Is there a way to get Ethereum price data using the Coinbase API? I've looked at the [documentation](https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/guides/price-data) and I only see a way to get Bitcoin price data.

Comment: https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/ETH-USD/spot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer thanks to [Roland Starke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5378743/roland-starke).

Here it is for those who are interested: https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/ETH-USD/spot

Answer (score 0):

This is curl for get any crypto price

```
curl https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/ETH-USD/spot
```

If you want other crypto price change ETH-USD for something else. You can also change /spot for buy and sell:

```
curl https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/ETH-USD/buy
curl https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/ETH-USD/sell
```

You will get respones with json data like:

```
{"data":{"base":"ETH","currency":"USD","amount":"3254.6"}}
```